# Local isometry between non-positively curved cube complexes

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, geometric-group-theory, cw-complexes

Let $X$, $Y$ be non-positively curved cube complexes and suppose there is a local isometry $X \to Y$. If $Y$ is special, then so is $X$.

This is Exercise 4.32 in M. Sageev's notes "CAT(0) Cube Complexes and Groups". It is somehow clear that this is true if one draws a picture, - but how can I prove this rigorously?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The definition of "special" is a definition with multiple cases. Have you tried to work out a rigorous proof of any one of the cases?

Comment: Yes, for instance I have tried to work out the proof for a hyperplane intersecting itself. It seems clear that the edges dual to a hyperplane remain dual if one looks at the vertices of the cube complex (however, no clue how to prove this), and since a hyperplane intersects itself iff two of its dual edges are incident, this should follow.

Comment: @Steven: A similar question has been asked here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870959/a-non-positively-curved-cube-complex-that-admits-a-local-isometric-embedding-int/1872491?noredirect=1#comment3860397_1872491